# string to boost::uint64_t fails with lexical_cast and stringsteam

Tags: c++, boost, 64-bit

I am trying to transform a string to a `boost::uint64_t` the contents of `pvalue` are `12345678901234567890`. the code I'm using right now is:

```
void setAttribute(EnumAttrTyoe pname, const void *pvalue) {
    if (pname == SESS_ID) {
        const char *raw_sess_id = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pvalue);
        std::string str_sess_id(raw_sess_id);
        std::cout << "Trying to open session id: '" << str_sess_id << "'\n";
        m_session_id = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned long long>(str_sess_id);
    }
}
```

This one throws an exception with message "bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target." If instead I use this code:

```
void setAttribute(EnumAttrTyoe pname, const void *pvalue) {
    if (pname == SESS_ID) {
        const char *raw_sess_id = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pvalue);
        std::string str_sess_id(raw_sess_id);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << raw_sess_id;
        ss >> m_session_id;
    }
}
```

it goes through but the value of `m_session_id` is 0. I have not yet check the flags of `ss` but I don't need to be a genious to know it fails. Any ideas what to do now?

**UPDATE** No C++11, since I cannot use it, and my compiler is VC++ 2008, boost version 1.43.0.

Comment: What compiler and boost versions are you using?

Comment: boost is 1.43.0, compiler MS VC++ 2008

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "12345678901234567890";

   std::uint64_t n = 0;
   ss >> n;

   std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```

Output over at http://liveworkspace.org:

> stdout: 
>   12345678901234567890

Answer (score 0):

I think your input C-style string is not what you think it is.  This use of `boost::lexical_cast` works for me on boost 1.42:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

int main() {
   std::string s = "12345678901234567890";
   boost::uint64_t i = boost::lexical_cast<boost::uint64_t>(s);
   std::cout << i << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

My guess is that your input is not zero-terminated, has a suffix you aren't expecting, or has an alternate encoding like UTF16.  Or perhaps it isn't even a string.

Comment: I though so too, (in fact that is the reason I built a string with it), in any case, I tried dumping the string, like std::cout << ss.str() << '\n' and the string is definitely there.

Comment: I wouldn't trust just a print of the string as there may be embedded non-printing characters.  I would set a breakpoint in your function and examine the memory at `pvalue`.  It should only contain hex values from 0x30 to 0x39 until the terminating 0x00.  Alternatively you can loop over the string and test with [isdigit()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).